# Latest Spring Boot upgrade is throwing Invalid property 'text[encryption] from SecurityProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I upgraded spring boot to latest release 1.2.0.RELEASE and now ends up with following exception.

```
used by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'text[encryption]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'text[encryption]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'text[encryption]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'text[encryption]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:950)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:926)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:749)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:645)
at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:119)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:630)
at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:251)
at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:225)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:296)
```

Other dependencies used:

```
<spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
<spring-data.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring-data.version>
```

Any idea what could be the reason. Thanks for your help

Comment: Post the properties file. It looks like you tried to name a property `text[encryption]`.

Comment: I do not have/aware about such a property

Comment: This log was confusing. I had security.text.encryption

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2246) to improve the error message

Comment: @AndyWilkinson  Isn't it better to file a bug to allow unknown properties. How does it impact spring security? Clients will not be able to upgrade with out refactoring due to this issue. Thank your for you help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like you have the following property in your application.properties or application.yml:

```
security.text.encryption
```

You should not have any custom properties that starts from 'security' because of spring-boot will try to map it to the SecurityProperties.

SecurityProperties configuration:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
```

Means it will fail on any unknown properties that started from 'security'

Comment: Thank you. I had many custom defined properties starting with security.